Issues importing and registering GSAP ScrollTrigger plugin
I'm having issues registering my Scroll Trigger plugin. When I console.log(gsap.plugin), the ScrollTrigger property is not there and none of my DOM elements are animating.
importing gsap and ScrollTrigger:
import  gsap  from "gsap"
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

Registering the plugin:
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger); 
I am getting a multiple browsers warning all similar: Invalid property  set to  Missing plugin? gsap.registerPlugin()
Here is my ts config:
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "outDir": "./dist",

Using gsap version ^3.12.5
I have tried installing useGSAP hook and using this instead of the useLayoutEffect. I have tried importing gsap as { gsap } and ScrollTrigger as { ScrollTrigger }. I have also tried these scripts in my index.html:
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

Any advice much appreciated

You can import ScrollTrigger pluigin from 'gsap/all' in reactjs.
Here is the code sample below.
import gsap from 'gsap';
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/all';

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

